# Windows Batch File - Automated FTP, Problem with Output Redirection

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I'm having an odd problem with a batch file that is used to FTP a file.  The log file is getting populated with the text that is ECHOed by the batch file but it does not contain the output of the FTP command.

Any thoughts?

**Command**

```
psend.bat 1234356.cmd 123456.log
```

**Batch File**

```
echo Starting >%2
echo %1 >>%2
echo %2 >>%2
echo Starting FTP >>%2
echo ftp -n -s:%1 >>%2 2>>%2
echo Finished FTP
```

**Log File**

```
Starting
123456.cmd
123456.log
Starting FTP
Finished FTP
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include -v (verbose) in the arguments to ftp command I guess.
Like - `ftp -n -i -v -s:%1`